# Changing base url to allow relative links

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that is located in a sub-directory:

`Ex. http://www.example.com/subdirectory`

However, when I create link in my website I must include the sub-directory folder in my relative urls, or the path will be incorrect. This is a problem because I am always transferring websites, and it's becoming tedious.

Is there a way to force the root url as `http://www.example.com/subdirectory` when creating relative urls?

For example, I would like to create a relative url in my pages without having to worry about the extra folder being included (i.e. I want to write it like this in my pages '/wp-content/theme/twentyten/images/sample.png')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<base href="http://www.example.com/subdirectory">`
or, for links to open in new tabs:
`<base href="http://www.example.com/subdirectory target="_blank">`

You should add this to your header.php in Appearance > Editor

Comment: Hi Ian, I tried this exact solution, except that when I added this url `('/wp-content/themes/twentyten/image.png')`, it still used the main domain as the root (http://www.example.com), instead of the root that I want, `http://www.example.com/subdirectory`

Comment: Remove the slash in the front `('wp-content/themes/twentyten/image.png')` (I think)

Comment: I also tried that too, but then that doesn't work after transferring the site to a new domain - so I still have to change all the links:)

Comment: That should work. Make sure the base tag is above everything else in your <head>

Comment: Are you doing this in your CSS, or just on a page? If it's just a page, it should work

Comment: Yes, that does work....must have missed something earlier!  Now how can I link to home using a relative url.  When I use `/` it directs me to very absolute domain - still.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29278/discussion-between-ian-carroll-and-rob-myrick)

Comment: Make sure that both your Site URL and WordPress URL are set correctly in Settings->General. Also, you may need to refresh your rewrite rules (change your permalinks setting and then change it back).